# What information will be send if a user make a normal http request?

Tags: php, http

I know I can get the user ip:
$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

the user user's agent:
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

What else information can I get from the user from a normal http request? Thank you.

Comment: Well, nothing is guaranteed.  What information are you looking for?

Comment: I believe it's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, not `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `phpinfo()` on a test page, you can see the values that will get back for your current webserver.  The results different from server to server but should be consistent on your server.  You are best to Google the names too, to see their exact purpose and meaning.

You can also use `print_r($_SERVER);` to list the server variables specifically.

Comment: Why would it be consistent on a server?  It has more to do with the client's request headers.

Comment: @Matthew unfortunately, there is no $_CLIENT variable in PHP. So, you have to stuck with $_SERVER.

Comment: @Col, I know that.  My point is that even on a particular server, the contents of `$_SERVER`, mainly for the request header keys (those starting with HTTP_), will vary by request.

Comment: That is true, there are many variables that you can't count on being there every time, but on a given server, the web server has many that it always provides.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "normal"?  Even the [user agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) is not required.  It is a "should" not a "must".  The W3C has [a list](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14) (part of RFC 2616) of major headers that may be there.